# Scala generator from function

Tags: scala, generator

I have producing function from Java API and Java code looks  like

```
val iter = dict.getIndexWordIterator(typeWord)

while (iter.hasNext){ 
    val witer = iter.next().getWordIDs() //witer: List[..] else finish
    .. //make common list from all  witer
}
```

I want to write generator for all this code and 'for' requests '<-' inside
so

```
(for(x <- 1 to 1000000; if iter.hasNext) yield iter.next.getWordIDs).flatten
```

can help but it is ugly and stupid for me. Is it possible to do this smarter?

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ // so we can treat java iterator as scala one
iter.take(1000000).flatMap(_.getWordIDs).toArray // or to something more suitable to you
```

The last step is optional -- you can keep your collection lazy and strict it some time later

Comment: I try to get generator from produced function and condision on it. I dont realise what and why foo here. x <- 1 to 100000 is dummy code just for 'for' request! I need to remove it..

Comment: @user2233374 so you're not interested in getting first N results? then drop the take step, you'll end up with `iter.flatMap(_getWordIDs).toArray`

Comment: iter is not Seq. it is object with "next" and "hasNext" methods only. It is not possible to compile "iter.flatMap(_getWordIDs)"

Comment: @user2233374 if iter is `java.util.Iterator` the very first line I've written will solve this issue

Comment: @user2233374 here is the minimum and working example: http://www.scalakata.com/5274232be4b0b1a1c4dafbc3 (hit green button to get the result)